# How to link WebSocket requests for the same connection id for traceability?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-xray

Look at the following X-Ray service map
[image]

There are 2 requests the user makes, once he is connected to the Api Gateway Websocket.

1. `/auth` kicks off a step function and pauses at a determined step. It sends back a message to the WebSocket tunnel requesting another information to continue.
2. `/otp` is the user's second request once it receives the above callback. Then, the lambda function resumes the step function (by sending a `SendTaskSuccessRequest`).

I want to link these 2 requests into one flow in the X-Ray service map. How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

> There are 2 requests the user makes, once he is connected to the Api Gateway Websocket.

If you are `user`, `user` can use ADOT or X-Ray sdk instrument the application(the client), wraps 2 requests into one segment. If `user` is an external user, which is not managed by service provider, there is no solution to merge 2 traces in downstream.

Comment: The user is ‘me’ using ‘postman’. Not sure yet how to accomplish that.